# JobTracker not Running

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

While running MapReduce jar I am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTrackerNotYetInitializedException: JobTracker is not yet RUNNING
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.checkJobTrackerState(JobTracker.java:5199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getNewJobId(JobTracker.java:3543)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy2.getNewJobId(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy2.getNewJobId(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:944)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at com.sreejithpillai.excel.mapreduce.ExcelDriver.main(ExcelDriver.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

but `jps` command shows

```
15575 JobTracker
15471 SecondaryNameNode
15137 NameNode
16123 Jps
15733 TaskTracker
3720
```

I tried formatting namenode and restarted but still the problem exists.

I can see Job at http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp

Somebody please help.

Comment: Have you tried restarting jobtracker?

Answer (score 0):

From the question it is not clear that whether you have restarted jobtracker or not (after formatting namenode).

When ever you restart namenode, it is better to restart jobtracker. Even though jps shows the process up and running, it might be inconsistent state. You need to go to jobtracker logs and check if there are any errors

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using standalone, and after restarting I started all the services using start-all.sh

Answer (score 0):

What sort of configuraton are you using? Stand Alone mode, pseudo cluster mode or Fully Distributed mode? also run `hadoop fsck /` to check whether the hdfs is in **healthy state or in Corrupted state**(applicable largely over pseudo cluster when accessed remotely by more than one commodity machine)

```
[edureka@localhost ~]$ hadoop fsck /
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

15/12/03 11:07:58 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Connecting to namenode via http://localhost:50070
FSCK started by edureka (auth:SIMPLE) from /127.0.0.1 for path / at Thu Dec 03 11:07:58 IST 2015
....................................................................................................
................................................
/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/edureka/.staging/job_1448946364079_0184/job.jar:  Under replicated BP-1756909416-127.0.0.1-1411538715533:blk_1073781438_40623. Target Replicas is 10 but found 1 replica(s).
.
/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/edureka/.staging/job_1448946364079_0184/job.split:  Under replicated BP-1756909416-127.0.0.1-1411538715533:blk_1073781439_40624. Target Replicas is 10 but found 1 replica(s).
...
/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/edureka/.staging/job_1448946364079_0261/job.jar:  Under replicated BP-1756909416-127.0.0.1-1411538715533:blk_1073782193_41378. Target Replicas is 10 but found 1 replica(s).
.
/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/edureka/.staging/job_1448946364079_0261/job.split:  Under replicated BP-1756909416-127.0.0.1-1411538715533:blk_1073782194_41379. Target Replicas is 10 but found 1 replica(s).
...
/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/edureka/.staging/job_1448946364079_0282/job.jar:  Under replicated BP-1756909416-127.0.0.1-1411538715533:blk_1073782396_41581. Target Replicas is 10 but found 1 replica(s).
.
/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/edureka/.staging/job_1448946364079_0282/job.split:  Under replicated BP-1756909416-127.0.0.1-1411538715533:blk_1073782397_41582. Target Replicas is 10 but found 1 replica(s).
...........................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
..Status: HEALTHY
 Total size:    131322862 B
 Total dirs:    138
 Total files:   902
 Total symlinks:                0
 Total blocks (validated):      825 (avg. block size 159179 B)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   825 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       6 (0.72727275 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    1
 Average block replication:     1.0
 Corrupt blocks:                0
 Missing replicas:              54 (6.143345 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          1
 Number of racks:               1
FSCK ended at Thu Dec 03 11:07:59 IST 2015 in 130 milliseconds


The filesystem under path '/' is HEALTHY
```

***I am using a pseudo cluster mode*** and the same is being accessed by 17 machines currently. Somehow when the 4 cores of the machine where the VM  has been installed could not provide enough CPU to run the jobs. The hdfs gets corrupted. This happens when there is an overload on the VM.
Please specify the configuration that you are using.

---

Thankyou :)

Comment: Hi Aniruddha thanks, I am using pseducluster mode with a name node and datanode

Comment: Did you get any benefit from the above answer?